# can't get html td element using javascript in jsf application

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

and in JavaScript

```
 document.getElementById('myId');
```

This is not working in JSF application. However, the same is working if I save the generated HTML in my system and open it .

Any Help ?

Comment: I dont know the significance of this. I'll do from now. Thanks

Comment: Visit your profile page http://stackoverflow.com/users/205505/abhishek, reread all the questions you posted and set answers which actually helped in answering/solving the question/problem to accepted by ticking the big white **V** on left hand side of the answer. Also upvote answers which were actually valueable. Downvote answers which are wrong. Leave normal/nothing-new-to-add answers as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing JavaScript code for a component based MVC framework which generates HTML, like JSF, you should not focus on the source code of the component based MVC framework, but on its **generated HTML output**.

If you can't tell this beforehand based on the source code, then you need to just open up the page in your favourite webbrowser and then rightclick the page and choose *View Source*. You'll see that the generated *Client ID's* are prepended by the ID's of the [`UINamingContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) components (like `h:form`, `h:dataTable` and `f:subView`). If you don't specify an ID for each of them, you will get an autogenerated ID like `j_id_xxxx`. To ease the work, you need to specify an ID for them. E.g.

```
<h:form id="form">
```

Also see [this blog article](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) for more information and hints. [This blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) may also be useful to learn more about the wall between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript.

Comment: But for html elements like <table> or <td> the id in the generated html output is same as what I gave in my source code.

Comment: Then your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe you executed the JS too early (before the DOM tree is fully built up and loaded in memory). If you intent to execute the JS during page load, hook the `window.onload` or body's `onload` attribute.